# HTML Server Control in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, html

What is the difference between HTML Container Control and HTML Generic Control in asp.net? How can their properties be changed?

Answer (score 0):

Please go through this msdn link , you get the idea

[HTMl Generic Controls](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.htmlcontrols.htmlgenericcontrol.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

### [HtmlContainerControl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.htmlcontrols.htmlcontainercontrol.aspx) Class

Serves as the abstract base class for HTML server controls that map to HTML elements that are required to have an opening and a closing tag.

The most common controls with a closing tag are the `<form>`, `<table>`, `<tr>`, `<td>`, `<a>`, and `<span>` elements.

The `InnerText` and `InnerHtml` properties allow you to manipulate the content between the opening and closing tags of HtmlContainerControl-derived controls.

### [HtmlGenericControl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.htmlcontrols.htmlgenericcontrol.aspx) Class

Defines the methods, properties, and events for all HTML server control elements not represented by a specific .NET Framework class.

Use this class to represent an HTML server control element not directly represented by a .NET Framework class, such as `<span>`, `<div>`, `<body>`, or `<font>`.

Comment: So we can use HtmlGenericControl in all contexts, right? Is there any advantage if HtmlContainerControls is used instead.